# Create array of promises for future execution

Tags: angular, typescript, promise

I've created an array to store a list of promises that should run after a single call to Promise.all, however right after pushing this new Promise into the array it gets executed. How can I fix it?

```
let promises: any[] = [];

this.tasklistItems.forEach(element => {
  if (element.checked) {
     promises.push(new Promise(() => this.tasklistItemsService.delete(this.tasklist, element.id))); // It gets executed right after this line
  }
});

Promise.all(promises) // But I need to start executing here
  .then((res) => { // So I can get all responses at the same place, together
    this.notification.success('Success!', 'Rows removed.');
  },
  (err) => {
  });
```

### UPDATE

Following @Evert's suggestions, now I have the following code:

```
  const deferred = [];
  this.tasklistItems.forEach(element => {
    if (element.checked) {
      deferred.push(() => this.tasklistItemsService.delete(this.tasklist, element.id).subscribe());
    }
  });

  Promise.all(deferred.map(func => func()))
    .then(
      () => {
        this.notification.success('Sucess!', 'Rows removed.');
        this.refreshGrid();
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
        this.notification.error('Error!', 'Could not remove the selected rows.');
      }
    );
```

And this is my service using `HttpClient`:

```
  delete(tasklistId: number, id: number): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.http.delete(`${this.baseUrl}/${tasklistId}/items/${id}`)
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }
```

If I don't add the `subscribe()` to the `delete(...)` call, it is not executed and if I add it, the `refreshGrid()` is called before the delete occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is broken:

```
new Promise(() => this.tasklistItemsService.delete(this.tasklist, element.id)
```

Aside from that, promises generally execute immediately. They are not a mechanism to defer execution to a later point. Thankfully javascript has something extremely simple for this: a plain old function.

```
const deferred = [];
this.tasklistItems.forEach(element => {
  if (element.checked) {
    deferred.push(() => this.tasklistItemsService.delete(this.tasklist, element.id)));
  }
}

// Iterates over all stored functions, calls them all and returns the result as an array of promises.
Promise.all( deferred.map( func => func() ) );
```

Comment: It worked. But now the `this.tasklistItemsService.delete` is requiring the explicit call to subscribe() to get executed. I'll update the code in the question.

Comment: @JulianoNunesSilvaOliveira this is no longer something I can help with, because it's now (I think) an angular question, not a generic javascript + promises question. I will say though that if you need `subscribe` now, I think you would have needed it before too.

Comment: Solved the other error by converting the `HttpClient.delete` return using toPromise and removing the `subscribe()`.

Comment: That makes sense. I didn't realize `delete()` did not return a promise by default

Comment: It returns an `Observable`. Now everything is working as I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In general, `.forEach()` and `Promise.all()` don't mix well, and creating arrays of deferred promises adds some unnecessary steps. (Nolan Lawson's ["We have a problem with promises"](https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html) does a great job of talking through both of these issues.) As @Evert mentioned, this is because promises are "eager", and execute as soon as they are constructed.

It looks like you want to take an array, screen out unchecked options, and then resolve an array of promises from that. How about using `.filter()` and `.map()` directly within `Promise.all()`?

```
Promise.all(
  this.tasklistItems
    .filter(element => element.checked)
    .map(checkedElement => this.tasklistItemsService.delete(this.tasklist, checkedElement.id)
)
.then((res) => { // So I can get all responses at the same place, together
  this.notification.success('Success!', 'Rows removed.');
},
(err) => {});
```